# Node.js "Foreach is not a function " error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to parse through a nested JSON object from an API call but I keep getting the error `foreach` is not a function

```js
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
    data = response.toJSON.;

    console.log(data);

    data.pagination.forEach(obj => {
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
        });
        console.log('-------------------');
    });

});
```

Comment: can you post also your JSON or part of it?

Comment: `response.toJson.` ist not a valid syntax...I think `toJson` is a function so you should call it like this `response.toJson()`...what do you get as a result of logging `data`?

Comment: the log says Exception from a finished function: TypeError: body.toJSON is not a function 
even when I use   data = body.toJSON();

Comment: You should use JSON.parse() instead.

Comment: I don't no the request module very well, but I don't think there is a response.toJson funciton / property. Instead, I think response is already a parsed object, so you should be able to just use the response object

Comment: But what I would suggest is not using the request module at all since it has been deprecated.

Comment: @MrCodingB Yes, It should not be used anymore as it is deprecated, Also, the body(response type has to be application/json) to parse body to JSON. Though request provides optional parameter {json: true} which can parse body data to it and you don't need to explicitly parse it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two `forEach` loops in the code. As you haven't mentioned in the question, there might be issues in both or in any one of them.

It seems First loop is having an issue, if `data.pagination.forEach` is not an array, you won't be able to iterate through it. If it's an object(key, value), you can use for/in.

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
    data = JSON.parse(body); // this is the data you need to process in the request

    console.log(data);

    data.pagination.forEach(obj => {
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
        });
        console.log('-------------------');
    });

});
```

Also, I would suggest don't use request as it is deprecated instead use other modules. You can check the list [here](https://syndicode.com/blog/request-node-module-for-http-requests-is-going-into-maintenance-mode-meet-its-alternatives/).

Comment: im using axios now but how do i loop through it like an object, here is my default code

Comment: axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
 console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
 console.error(error);
})

Comment: You only need to change to axios rest will remain same that means you will be looping the same way as you were doing in the request callback. Are you able to get the data? I would suggest you to ask a new question if you are unable to get the data. I can answer it.

Comment: thanks for the help,i have asked again here, link below

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045206/loop-through-axios-request-data-in-node-error

Comment: Posted the answer on the link.