# Loop through axios request.data in node error

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

i have been trying to loop through an axios request but i keep getting the error in my logs, i am trying  to loop through my data, the returned structure of my data looks like this

```
{2 items
"data":[1 item
0:{...}34 items
]
"pagination":{4 items
"page":0
"itemsPerPage":0
"hasNextPage":true
"hasPrevPage":true
}
}
```

here is the error

```
scheduledFunction
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

here is my code

```
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://elenasport-io1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures',
  params: {to: d3, page: '1', from: d2},
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-key': '63836fd5cemshe5de364e7512350p145aebjsn744427db1224',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'elenasport-io1.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {



    //console.log(response.data);


    data = JSON.parse(response.data); // this is the data you need to process in the request

    console.log(data);

    data.pagination.forEach(obj => {
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
        });
        





}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});





})
```

Comment: Is `response.data` actually JSON? I'd reckon you already have the parsed object here! What does `console.log(response.data);` output?

Comment: what does `typeof response.data` return ?

Comment: Be careful, you've put your secret api key in your question ! `x-rapidapi-key : ...`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to parse data to JSON if it is not coming as the JSON. Here, you are already getting the response data as JSON, you don't need to parse it again.

```
axios.request(options).then(function (response) {

    console.log(typeof response); // check the type of response returning already in JSON format
    console.log(response); // check the response object and based on key/values process it 

    const data = response.data; // if resp contains the data you will get it here.

    console.log(data);

    data.pagination.forEach(obj => {
        Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
        });  

}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});

})
```

Note : Axios parses the response based on the HTTP response's Content-Type header. When the response's content type is application/json , Axios will automatically try to parse the response into a JavaScript object. For more details check [this](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/response-body#:%7E:text=Axios%20parses%20the%20response%20based,response%20into%20a%20JavaScript%20object.&text=Keep%20in%20mind%20that%20the%20response%20headers%20are%20sent%20by%20the%20server.).

Also, pagination is an object, which is not iterable instead use for/in

```
         
axios.request(options).then(function (response) {

    console.log(typeof response); // check the type of response returning already in JSON format
    console.log(response); // check the response object and based on key/values process it 

    const data = response.data; // if resp contains the data you will get it here.

    console.log(data);

  for (let data1 in data.pagination) {
    // from the sample response you shared in the question 
    console.log(data1) // prints the keys
    console.log(data.pagination.data1) // prints the values

}

}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});

})
```

Comment: Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

`axios` returns response in `json` format. So, no need to parse your data.

Change your code

**from** `data = JSON.parse(response.data);`

**to** `const data = response.data;`

Happy coding :)